# Remove a level from a pandas MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to completely remove a level from a `MultiIndex`

```
import pandas as pd
tuples = [(0, 100, 1000),(0, 100, 1001),(0, 100, 1002), (1, 101, 1001)]
index_3levels=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples,names=["l1","l2","l3"])
print index_3levels.levels
[Int64Index([0, 1], dtype=int64), Int64Index([100, 101], dtype=int64), Int64Index([1000, 1001, 1002], dtype=int64)]
```

I would like to extract the first 2 levels, to achieve:

```
print index_2levels
MultiIndex
[(0, 100), (1, 101)]
```

`droplevel` drops the level but keeps the duplicates:

```
print index_3levels.droplevel("l3")
MultiIndex
[(0, 100), (0, 100), (0, 100), (1, 101)]
```

I could in principle call `unique` to remove them. However it does not look the right approach.
Is there a more direct method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This could be an enhancement to `droplevel`, maybe by passing `uniquify=True`

```
In [77]: MultiIndex.from_tuples(index_3levels.droplevel('l3').unique())
Out[77]: 
MultiIndex
[(0, 100), (1, 101)]
```

Here's another way to do this

First create some data

```
In [226]: def f(i):
            return [(i,100,1000),(i,100,1001),(i,100,1002),(i+1,101,1001)]

In [227]: l = []

In [228]: for i in range(1000000):
             l.extend(f(i))

In [229]: index_3levels=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(l,names=["l1","l2","l3"])

In [230]: len(index_3levels)
Out[230]: 4000000
```

The method shown above

```
In [238]: %timeit MultiIndex.from_tuples(index_3levels.droplevel(level='l3').unique())
1 loops, best of 3: 2.26 s per loop
```

Let's split the index apart to 2 components, l1, and l2 and uniquify, much
faster to unique these as these are Int64Index

```
In [249]: l2 = index_3levels.droplevel(level='l3').droplevel(level='l1').unique()

In [250]: %timeit index_3levels.droplevel(level='l3').droplevel(level='l1').unique()
10 loops, best of 3: 35.3 ms per loop

In [251]: l1 = index_3levels.droplevel(level='l3').droplevel(level='l2').unique()

In [252]: %timeit index_3levels.droplevel(level='l3').droplevel(level='l2').unique()
10 loops, best of 3: 52.2 ms per loop

In [253]: len(l1)
Out[253]: 1000001

In [254]: len(l2)
Out[254]: 2
```

Reassemble

```
In [255]: %timeit MultiIndex.from_arrays([ np.repeat(l1,len(l2)), np.repeat(l2,len(l1)) ])
10 loops, best of 3: 183 ms per loop
```

Total time about 270ms, pretty good speedup. Note that I think the ordering may be different, but I think some combination of np.repeate/np.tile will work

Comment: Another idea could be an enhancement to unique to return object of same class.

Comment: Thanks, however I wonder if there is a better solution, that does not require running `unique` which is pretty expensive. Afterall I just want to somehow extract 2 levels of the 3 in the `MultiIndex`, not create a new object.

Comment: unique is actually pretty fast here; what is your final goal?

Comment: On a large dataset of few million samples, unique is very slow. This solution gets exactly what I want, but I am looking for a more efficient method.